# Discord bot ctx is being displayed as argument

Tags: discord, discord.py

Thats a test code where im trying to work in classes. Even tho in commands it displayes ctx as required arg instead and it works only if i put it before self.

```py
class Quiz:
    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer



    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def quiz(self, ctx):
        fido = Quiz("Starter mass?", "yeah")
        nope = Quiz("WHAT?", "lel")
        await ctx.send(fido.question)

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'heh'

        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send('Right {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As crazy as it sounds, remove the `self` argument from your method. The commands decorator will take care of this. (You can also use a command cog)

```py
class Quiz:
    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer

    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def quiz(ctx):
        fido = Quiz("Starter mass?", "yeah")
        nope = Quiz("WHAT?", "lel")
        await ctx.send(fido.question)

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'heh'

        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send('Right {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

Also your check function doesn't work correctly. It always uses the `fido` question and says you are correct only after responding with `'heh'`.

```py
    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def quiz(ctx):
        fido = Quiz("Starter mass?", "yeah")
        nope = Quiz("WHAT?", "lel")
        question = random.choice((fido, nope))
        await ctx.send(question.question)

        check = lambda m: m.content.lower() == question.answer
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send(f'Right **{msg.author.name}**!')
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, problem solved and you really saved me with the code you sent!